# Django Wagtail pageurl template tag returning incorrect host name

Tags: django, uwsgi, wagtail

I'm using **Wagtail 1.8** and the **pageurl** template tag on a blog index page to hyperlink the titles of the blogs through to the actual blog pages. Pretty standard stuff. This is a **Django 1.10** project.

```
<a class="blog-post-link" href="{% pageurl blog %}">
    <h2>{{ blog.title }}</h2>
</a>
```

The very strange problem I'm having is that the host name of the site is being replaced by the host name of my server that is hosting the site. For example, a correct link would be:

https://beadtrails.com/blog/vernon-bc-what-to-do-on-and-off-the-trails/

However, it is sometime being returned as https://graphicearth.ca/blog/vernon-bc-what-to-do-on-and-off-the-trails/

When I say sometimes, if I go to the wagtail admin sites page, then into the host record and save it, it will fix the problem--for a while. It will then revert back to the incorrect url.

As you can imagine, this is not a great situation where your blog links end in a 404 error!

For trouble shooting, I've checked the config of both Wagtail and Django sites tables, checked the config files correctly identify the SITE_ID, done a text search through all the source code for 'graphicearth.ca', reviewed the uWSGI and nginx config files, checked that the blog hierarchy is correct within Wagtail relative to the home page, checked the headers in the browser to make sure the right host is being passed. Everything looks ok.

Digging into the source code for the template tag, which is in wagtailcore_tags.py, the comments for the function says:

> Outputs a page's URL as relative (/foo/bar/) if it's within the same
>   site as the current page, or absolute (http://example.com/foo/bar/) if
>   not.

So for some reason, the code ends up thinking that the sites are different--but not all the time. As mentioned above, if I go into the Wagtail admin and re-save the sites entry it fixes things for a while.

As this is on a production system, it's rather hard to debug. Does anyone have any suggestions on what might be causing this and/or how to debug it?

Application stack is:
 - Django 1.10.5
 - Wagtail 1.8
 - uWSGI
 - nginx

**Answer update:**
Tom's response was what led me to find the solution so I've marked his answer as correct. I was using the same memcached instance for multiple sites and the keys must of been getting crossed. I reverted to basic django cache and it resolved the problem. Time to find a better solution for caching with multiple sites on the same server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a cache configured on the production system? The `pageurl` template tag calls [get_site_root_paths()](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/f960753d743d77233802da800ad0f55f569f640c/wagtail/wagtailcore/models.py#L202) which uses a cache of site root paths if one is available. The cache *should* be purged if sites are edited or deleted, but perhaps you could try [configuring settings.CACHES to use DummyCache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/cache/#dummy-caching-for-development) to help track down the issue.

Comment: As a follow-on thought to this - is graphicearth.ca another Wagtail instance on the same server? It's possible that they're sharing the same cache, and the `wagtail_site_root_paths` key is colliding between the two installations. If so, the easiest fix is to add a `KEY_PREFIX`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/cache/#cache-key-prefixing

Comment: Yes, it does seem to be an issue with the cache--I'm running memcached. Still tracking down the exact fix and will post an update when I'm certain it's stable. Thanks for your answer.